# UITableViewCell isn't deleted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell. First time works perfectly, but when I reload data the old cells are not deleted, while the new cells appear on them.
This is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                  reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
}
Contact * cellContact = [contactsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:[self createViewForCellWithContact:cellContact]];
return cell;
```

}

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Cells are not deleted when you reload the data, they are reused. New cells aren't appearing; new subviews are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
```

You are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with identifier "Cell" for all rows, that means a single cell is created and being used for each and every row.

Proper way to do this is to create a custom UiTableViewCell class, and reuse it by just changing the content.

since you didnt give the details of the tableviewcell you are showing. 
here is some simple ways to solve the issue

1) instead of reusing the same cell create new cell for every row
(but this will take lot of memory, because instead of reusing a single cell, we are creating cell for each row)

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
```

2) remove your subview of the cell and add again

In your createViewForCellWithContact method add tag to the view you are returning and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method
remove the view from cell before adding another subview

```
UIView *removeView= [cell viewWithTag:1];
[removeView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

everytime that method gets called you add a subview to the content view of the cell. thats why there are more and more views in the cell and it appears as if they are on top of each other!

what happens in your `createViewForCellWithContact`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a custom UITableViewCell you do not need to programatically add a custom cell to a UITableViewCell's view. Instead you should just initialize your custom cell and return it.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath){
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell"
    Contact *cell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithIndentifier:identifier];
    if(cell==nil)
        cell = [Contact alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
              reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];
   //Do thing specific to this cell, set custom variables

    return cell;
}
```